# Reading xml from url with QXmlQuery (without temporary file)

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I download a xml file from server.
I can parse it with QXmlQuery  if its written to file, but
how  can i parse it from the 'reply'  (QNetworkReply)?

There is a QXmlStreamReader but i don't seem to find a way
to connect reader and query

*EDIT* i don't know how to turn reply in QIODevice,

```
reply->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QXmlQuery query1;
QXmlNamePool namePool(query1.namePool());
query1.bindVariable(QXmlName(namePool, QString("kmlFile")),reply->readAll());
```

but i get error

```
QXmlQuery::bindVariable(const QXmlName &,const QXmlItem &)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'QByteArray' to 'const QXmlItem &'
```

Comment: `QFile` and `QNetworkReply` have `QIODevice` as base class. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager( this );
QNetworkReply* reply = QNetworkAccessManager::get( manager->get( QNetworkRequest( QUrl("http://www.foo.com/example.xml") ) ) ;
//QXmlStreamReader reader( reply );
QXmlQuery query;
query.setQuery(reply);
```

also there is a method
`void QXmlQuery::setQuery ( const QUrl & queryURI, const QUrl & baseURI = QUrl() )`

Comment: how do i use QXmlQuery with QXmlStreamReader?

Comment: with void QXmlQuery::setQuery ( QIODevice * sourceCode, const QUrl & documentURI = QUrl() ) or you just can create a QXmlQuery query;query.setQuery(reply);